# Best practice for KVO observing model changes in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

Let's imagine a basic iPhone app with a table view to show a list of people and a details view to change the name of a person embedded in a navigation controller.

I'm using KVO to get notified in my table view controller that the name of a person was changed down in the details controller.

My question is when/where to add and remove my table view controller as observer for the `name` of each person object.

My approach:

```
@implementation PeopleTableViewController 

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Person *person = ...; // person for index path

    [person addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:0 context:(__bridge void *)(PERSON_NAME_CTX)];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Person *person = ...; // person for index path

    [person removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name"];

    // This is not called when the view is removed from the hierarchy
    // Can't use viewDidDisappear: because we are using a navigation controller
    // and tableView:willDisplayCell: is not called when we return from the details controller
}

- dealloc {
    // See comment in didEndDisplayingCell:

    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        Person *person = ...; // person for index path

        [person removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name"];
    }
}
```

Due to the navigation controller things are a bit tricky, because `tableView: didEndDisplayingCell` is not called when the view is removed from the view hierarchy. I can't remove the observer in `viewWillDisappear:`, because when the user returns from the details controller I still need to observe the person objects for changes.

Removing the observer in `dealloc` seems to work. My question: is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should call addObserver/removeObserver on viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear methods respectively, because dealloc method is not balanced with this calls (I mean can be called few times than the methods above). Maybe one of the best solutions is use a NSFetchedResultsController in order to track any change to the data source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not use Core Data so I can't use `NSFetchedResultsController`. Also, I can't remove the observer in `viewWillDisappear:`, because I need to be notified of changes that the user makes in the detail view controller. (I'm using a navigation controller)

Comment: I see, I think that is better to perform a reload data on viewWillAppear:

Comment: Why reload? That would work, but does not seem right. Everything is already set up nicely. The navigation controller takes care of everything. All I need to do is update my view after a model changed down in another view controller.

Comment: Yes, but take into consideration that if all the changes (name changes) happen on a pushed viewController then the cells are not visible (and cannot be updated). reloading data on viewWillAppear is a better approach than observing value changes. KVO in this case doesn't makes sense, because the updates on cells are not real time.

Comment: Ok, I'll give viewWillAppear: a try. Thanks!